# Heroku App + Custom Domain - Specify Canonical Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, canonical-link

I have a Rails app on Heroku that I've set up with a custom domain.

I noticed that in Google search results, the herokuapp link appears instead of the custom domain. I'd like the custom domain to be the default that appears in search results.

I looked up how to do this and found this response:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65376/how-to-get-rid-of-heroku-app-domain-in-the-search-resutls

I've verified my site using Google's Webmaster Tools, but when I try to specify the preferred domain, I see the text "Restricted to root level domains only."

**How can I specify my preferred domain in Google search results for my Heroku app with a custom domain?**